# Subversion Control server that is accessible by different OS?

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

My company is planning to use subversion control server that is accessible to to every employee to improve the workflow. The problem is everyone is using different operating system hence we want to setup a server accessible to all different OS simultaneously.

So here is my question what OS should be used to setup the SVN server in (is linux a good choice?). And secondly if we use different SVN clients (for different OS) can we use the same server effectively?? I am looking for a free option only. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter which OS the SVN server is running on. All clients will be able to use the server without a problem. If you're looking for a free option, go with Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion can run on many different operating systems and no matter what operating system you run the server on, the clients can use any supported operating system for that client. You can also use different client software on different workstations, it does not need to be the same.

http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#portability